# Fixing an array of gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with this array. I need to set the gameobjects in the inspector, but I have an issue with `renderer.gameobject`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour, IRecyle
{

public GameObject[] obstacles;

public void Restart()
{
    var renderer = GetComponent<GameObject>();
    renderer.gameObject = obstacles[Random.Range(0, obstacles.Length)];
}

public void Shutdown()
{

}
}
```

Comment: Oh, I do love a good cliffhanger. And the issue is....? Is it by any chance that you haven't assigned a value to `obstacles`?

Comment: Also, I didn't understand what are you trying to do here: var renderer = GetComponent<GameObject>();

Comment: GameObject is not a component so you can’t use GetComponent with it.

Comment: renderer itself is GameObject and i dont understand what do you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Renderers are not GameObjects. They are Components.

GameObjects are containers of Components - one GameObject holds many Components.

This line is invalid (GameObjects are not Components!):

```
//Invalid!
var renderer = GetComponent<GameObject>();
```

You should not set a Component's `gameObject` property! This will **not** magically attach the Component to the new gameObject:

```
//Don't do this!!
renderer.gameObject = someGameObject
```

Instead:

```
Renderer rend = someGameObject.AddComponent<Mesh renderer>();
```